# Oracle SQL Grouping In Ranges

Tags: sql, oracle, grouping, gaps-and-islands

I am looking for ideas on how to group numbers into low and high ranges in Oracle SQL. I looking to to avoid cursors...any ideas welcome

Example input

| ID | LOW | HIGH |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 2 |
| A | 2 | 3 |
| A | 3 | 5 |
| A | 9 | 11 |
| A | 11 | 13 |
| A | 13 | 15 |
| B | 0 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 4 |
| B | 7 | 9 |
| B | 11 | 12 |
| B | 12 | 17 |
| B | 17 | 18 |

Which would result in the following grouping into ranges

| ID | LOW | HIGH |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 5 |
| A | 9 | 15 |
| B | 0 | 4 |
| B | 7 | 9 |
| B | 11 | 18 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Gaps & Islands problem. You can use the traditional solution.

For example:

```
select max(id) as id, min(low) as low, max(high) as high
from (
  select x.*, sum(i) over(order by id, low) as g
  from (
    select t.*,
      case when low = lag(high) over(partition by id order by low) 
            and id = lag(id) over(partition by id order by low) 
           then 0 else 1 end as i
    from t
  ) x 
) y
group by g
```

Result:

```
 ID  LOW  HIGH 
 --- ---- ---- 
 A   0    5    
 A   9    15   
 B   0    4    
 B   7    9    
 B   11   18
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gerQhG-M).

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, you should use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` for row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY id
  ORDER BY low, high
  MEASURES
    FIRST(low) AS low,
    MAX(high) AS high
  PATTERN (overlapping* last_row)
  DEFINE
    overlapping AS NEXT(low) <= MAX(high)
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (id, low, high) AS
SELECT 'A',  0,  2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A',  2,  3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A',  3,  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A',  9, 11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 11, 13 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 13, 15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B',  0,  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B',  1,  4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B',  7,  9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 11, 12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 12, 17 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 17, 18 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C',  0, 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C',  1,  3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C',  5,  8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C',  9, 15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 10, 14 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 11, 13 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | LOW | HIGH |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 5 |
| A | 9 | 15 |
| B | 0 | 4 |
| B | 7 | 9 |
| B | 11 | 18 |
| C | 0 | 15 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3thVOJia)