# Gaps and Islands with continuous ranges from previous row

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following set of Data

| SET | START | END | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 10 | 10 |
| A | 11 | 20 | 10 |
| A | 21 | 30 | 10 |
| B | 51 | 60 | 10 |
| B | 61 | 70 | 10 |
| B | 81 | 90 | 10 |
| B | 91 | 100 | 10 |
| C | 101 | 200 | 100 |
| C | 201 | 300 | 100 |
| C | 401 | 500 | 100 |

And wanted to have the following result:

| SET | START | END | TOTAL_QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 30 | 30 |
| B | 51 | 70 | 20 |
| B | 81 | 100 | 20 |
| C | 101 | 300 | 200 |
| C | 401 | 500 | 100 |

So it will check previous "End" range and if it's a continuous from the previous "Start" range then it will be grouped into one "Start - End" ranges with the Sum of Qty.
I don't know how this can be achieved with Oracle SQL, can anyone help?

Comment: can you present both the data you have and the result you're looking for in a table format?

Comment: i dont know why it's not coming as tabular format :(( in preview it's in tabular format but when I post it become like that

Comment: user20194675: Because you didn't format it correctly. Look at the edit that was made for you by @nbk to learn how to format tables here, or look at the formatting help using the **?** button on the editing toolbar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle SQL Grouping In Ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73952566/oracle-sql-grouping-in-ranges). To get the quantity, add `sum(qty)` to the select list for `row_number` solution or to the `measures` clause for `match_recognize` solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select   "SET"
         ,min("START") as "START"
         ,max("END")   as "END"
         ,sum(QTY)     as  QTY
from     (
         select   t.*
                  ,count(mrk) over(partition by "SET" order by "START") as grp
         from    (
                 select  t.*
                        ,case when "START" - lag("END") over(partition by "SET" order by "START") > 1 then 1 end as mrk
                 from    t
                 ) t
         ) t

group by "SET", grp
```

| SET | START | END | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 30 | 30 |
| B | 51 | 70 | 20 |
| B | 81 | 100 | 20 |
| C | 101 | 300 | 200 |
| C | 401 | 500 | 100 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9kaIWULr)